# Where should I create a template for a json view in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.1

I am using CakePHP 3.1 and trying to render the json index response for `User` model. I followed the [CakePHP manual page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-template-files) and created `index.ctp` under the directory `src/Template/Users/json/`, but the file does not get hooked by the controller. I also tried `src/View/Users`, which also did not work. Should I specify a file to render or something else? In `src/Controller/UsersController.php`, I have `index()` method with

> $users = $this->paginate('Users');
>   $this->set(compact('users'));

Comment: Did you also [add the json extension in the Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `AppController.php`. Since version 3.1.0 this sets the `_serialize` to true by default. Therefore the template files are all ignored.

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
    ) {
        $this->set('_serialize', true);
    }
}
```

You need to remove that code from `beforeRender`.